# Why was my on-hold question deleted before I had a chance to clarify?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

This is in regard to this question that was deleted:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474290/filling-php-arrays-with-mysql-query-results

Giving no reason to delete (not close) the question wasn't very helpful to me. If you need clarification then why not just ask for clarification?

If I have an actual issue I need help with, this sort of treatment seems disingenuous. Notice I haven't been rude to anyone on this site.

Comment: eh, that seems like a relatively clear, on topic question to me. though, it also looks like an X/Y problem (which doesn't make it off topic, just makes it less useful.)

Comment: It being an X/Y problem means you need to better explain *why* you need the mysql data stored in the php array the way you do. Otherwise, the answer is going to be "don't do that" (though it may be that anyway after you explain)

Comment: But "don't do that" is a good answer if I am actually wrong.

Comment: @JAL What's back?

Comment: @Don'tPanic By the time I saw this meta post and followed the link, the question had already been undeleted.

Comment: Ohh, I get it. Sorry I was a little slow there.

Comment: @posfan12 you need to be a lot more active when you post a S.O question, expect comments\answers within seconds\minutes. Nothing is more frustrating than waiting for you to reply.

Comment: It was less than an hour since I asked the question.

Comment: "seconds\minutes" seriously we are that active.

Comment: @posfan12 you may look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php and see how fast questions fall out of that view - if you want your post noticed you better be around while people can still see it (indeed you can eventually add bounty to get more views again but it is not as free as watching post for first 10 minutes while people can see it).

Comment: @Dagon Nobody says you have to wait for OP to reply. 5 other people can reopen the question, should it be necessary.

Comment: Side note, I don't speak that guttural language, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490482/are-there-dictionaries-in-php seems a better choice than using standard array indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that deleting your question was unwarranted, I'd even go as far as calling it abuse of privileges. Deleting on-hold questions that quickly should be reserved for questions that are beyond saving and cannot be edited into a good, on-topic question.

It has been undeleted now due to the attention here.

Comment: Thank you for reopening the question.

Comment: @posfan12 I assume you mean *for undeleting*, your question is still on-hold and you'll need to edit it in order to convince people to reopen it. Follow the advice of KevinB here and DontPanic at your SO question.

Comment: @Stijn can you reference the rules for deleting?

Comment: @Dagon I'd have to search if there are written rules, but common sense should be enough. See [What is a “closed” or “on hold” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question): *"If a question has been closed (except as a duplicate), then for the first 5 days, it is marked as “on hold” rather than “closed”. This is meant to convey that the question requires improvement and may be reopened if improved. During this period, if the question is edited by anyone, it will be added to the reopen queue."*

Comment: @Dagon That means that the SO team would like people to edit their question within 5 days. Deleting it after only a couple of hours when it can be turned into a good question without trouble, is unproductive.

Comment: The question is gone again, not 24 hours later?

Comment: @Gimby legit deletion this time, it seems. Quoting OP: *"I tried this earlier and it was not working. I just did another test and it seems to work. I must have made an unrelated error. Until I figure out what, this thread can probably be closed. – posfan12 15 hours ago "*